# Cómo acceder a una variable dentro de una función y usar en otro archivo js

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, javascript-import

estoy haciendo para practicar un carrito de compras.
Utilicé diferentes códigos de diferentes lugares que he encontrado en la web.
El carrito funciona bien, pero quiero automatizar algunas configuraciones desde una planilla de google sheet.
Para ello utilicé la libreria Tabletop. Entonces, desde la planilla genera un JSON y lo recupero en mi archivo tabletop.js.
Recibo dentro de una función un arreglo de objetos con los datos de la planilla. El problema, es que quiero acceder al valor de la clave "Costo_de_Envío" y utilizarla en otro archivo que tiene las configuraciones. No logro "extraer" el valor, ya que si declaro la variable de forma global y la inicializo en 0, luego no puedo extraer el valor que viene de la planilla ya que está dentro de una función. En la consola de desarrollador marca siempre 0.

**Archivo tabletp.js**

```
var publicSpreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/......';

const costoEnvio = 0;



function init() {
  Tabletop.init( {
    key: publicSpreadsheetUrl,
    callback: showInfo,
    parseNumber: true,
    simpleSheet: true 
  } )
}

function showInfo(data, tabletop) {

  console.log(data);
  
  
  const envio = data.map( function (d){
    return `${d.Costo_de_Envío}`;
  })
 
 const [costoEnvio] = envio;
 console.log(costoEnvio);

}
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)
```

El console.log(data); muestra en consola:

```
[{…}]
0:
Costo_de_Envío: "80"
Descripción: "Esto es una demo de la Tienda"
Email de la Tienda: "contacto@tienda.com"
Logotipo: "https://img.auctiva.com/imgdata/1/9/5/1/4/3/4/webimg/1085293295_o.png"
Medios de Pago: "paypal"
Moneda de la Tienda: "USD"
Nombre_de_la_Tienda: "Mi tienda"
N° WhatsAPP Pedidos: "5554847534"
```

El console.log(costoEnvio) muestra en consola:

```
80  // en valor númerico
```

**script en el archivo html**
Donde quiero usar el valor de la variable "costoEnvio"

```
<script>
      $("body").tienda({

       
        // global shipping charges in amount
        shippingCharges: 0,

      });
    </script>
```

Cuando uso la variable en est último código siempre queda en 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede acceder a una variable **creada** dentro de una función desde fuera de la función, pero lo que se puede hacer es:

- Que la función retorne el valor, o bien
- Que la función modifique una variable que está fuera

De cualquier manera hay un problema en tu código, en mi opinión y es que las dos versiones de `costoEnvio` son de tipos distíntos, uno es un entero y el otro es un array. El entero además es `const` osea que no se puede modificar. Suponiendo que el tipo correcto es array:

Modificando una variable creada afuera:

```js
let costoEnvio = []; //<-- No es const, tiene que ser var o let

function showInfo(envio) {
  //codigo
  costoEnvio = envio; // <-- modifica la variable de afuera siempre que no pongamos const, let o var
                      
}


showInfo([40, 60, 100])

console.log(costoEnvio)
```

De cualquier manera, me parece mejor la opción de que la función retorne el valor:

```js
const costoEnvio = function(envio) { // <-- La función si puede ser const
  //codigo
  return envio;
}

console.log(costoEnvio([10, 20, 40]))
```

El tema de que sean archivos distíntos no afecta a este problema.

De paso, también se pueden hacer algo como esto:

```js
function showInfo(datos)
{    
    this.costoEnvio=datos;
    this.costoTotal=datos.map(e=>e*1.2);
}

const informacion = new showInfo([40,30,20]);

console.log(informacion.costoEnvio);
console.log(informacion.costoTotal);
```

En verdad cuando hacemos `new` el resultado es un `object` no es mas una función, mientras es función no se puede acceder.